# PostgreSQL Query performance on an indexed text field

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Hello Fellow Engineers,

I have a query that is performing poorly and thought adding an index would be an easy quick fix, with a positive transformation effect on performance.

It look like I was wrong so I am here to ask your advice, please.

The table is in essence very simple and contains ~10,000 entries, and looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE phrase
(
    phrase_id bigint NOT NULL,
    phrase text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT phrase_pkey PRIMARY KEY (phrase_id),
    CONSTRAINT phrase_phrase_key UNIQUE (phrase)
)
```

After dropping/creating the indexes, I ran a VACUUM ANALYZE on the table before running any explanations/queries.

Running the following query with no index takes about 82ms, a rough average over a few tries.Running explain gives:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT phrase FROM phrase WHERE upper(phrase) = ANY('{*PROTEIN SHAKE,*APPLE PIE}');
"Seq Scan on phrase  (cost=0.00..295.72 rows=100 width=18) (actual time=0.049..5.730 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (upper(phrase) = ANY ('{"*PROTEIN SHAKE","*APPLE PIE"}'::text[]))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 10046"
"Planning Time: 0.135 ms"
"Execution Time: 5.745 ms"
```

There might be a few phrases to pull back, so I was looking at ILIKE as follows:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT phrase FROM phrase WHERE upper(phrase) ~~* ANY('{*PROTEIN SHAKE,*APPLE PIE}');;
"Seq Scan on phrase  (cost=0.00..295.72 rows=2 width=18) (actual time=0.113..19.492 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (upper(phrase) ~~* ANY ('{"*PROTEIN SHAKE","*APPLE PIE"}'::text[]))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 10046"
"Planning Time: 0.081 ms"
"Execution Time: 19.510 ms"
```

After creating a btree index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX phrase_phrase_idx ON phrase USING BTREE (upper(phrase) text_pattern_ops ASC NULLS LAST)
```

The equality query gives the following explanation; running this query takes about 85ms.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT phrase FROM phrase WHERE upper(phrase) = ANY('{*PROTEIN SHAKE,*APPLE PIE}');
"Index Only Scan using phrase_phrase_btree_idx on phrase  (cost=0.29..8.61 rows=2 width=18) (actual time=0.031..0.034 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: ((upper(phrase)) = ANY ('{"*PROTEIN SHAKE","*APPLE PIE"}'::text[]))"
"  Heap Fetches: 0"
"Planning Time: 0.100 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.112 ms"
```

The ILIKE query gives the following explanation; running this query takes about 95ms.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT phrase FROM phrase WHERE upper(phrase) ~~* ANY('{*PROTEIN SHAKE,*APPLE PIE}');
"Seq Scan on phrase  (cost=0.00..295.72 rows=2 width=18) (actual time=0.116..19.043 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (upper(phrase) ~~* ANY ('{"*PROTEIN SHAKE","*APPLE PIE"}'::text[]))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 10046"
"Planning Time: 0.247 ms"
"Execution Time: 19.060 ms"
```

I thought it might be worth a try sticking the values in the index, to save a trip to the table:

```
CREATE INDEX phrase_phrase_idx ON phrase USING BTREE (upper(phrase) text_pattern_ops ASC NULLS LAST) INCLUDE(phrase_id, phrase);
```

Running the following query (not the explain) took about 85ms.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT phrase FROM phrase WHERE upper(phrase) = ANY('{*PROTEIN SHAKE,*APPLE PIE}');
"Seq Scan on phrase  (cost=0.00..295.72 rows=100 width=18) (actual time=0.046..5.734 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (upper(phrase) = ANY ('{"*)"","*APPLE PIE"}'::text[]))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 10046"
"Planning Time: 0.139 ms"
"Execution Time: 5.748 ms"
```

and this ILIKE query took about 95ms.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT phrase FROM phrase WHERE upper(phrase) ~~* ANY('{*PROTEIN SHAKE,*APPLE PIE}');
"Seq Scan on phrase  (cost=0.00..295.72 rows=2 width=18) (actual time=0.114..19.340 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (upper(phrase) ~~* ANY ('{"*PROTEIN SHAKE","*APPLE PIE"}'::text[]))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 10046"
"Planning Time: 0.094 ms"
"Execution Time: 19.357 ms"
```

I thought I'd try a GIN index:

```
CREATE INDEX phrase_phrase_gin_idx ON phrase USING GIN (upper(phrase) gin_trgm_ops)
```

The equate query took ~85ms.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT phrase FROM phrase WHERE upper(phrase) = ANY('{*PROTEIN SHAKE,*APPLE PIE}');
"Seq Scan on phrase  (cost=0.00..295.72 rows=2 width=18) (actual time=0.056..5.764 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (upper(phrase) = ANY ('{"*PROTEIN SHAKE","*APPLE PIE"}'::text[]))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 10046"
"Planning Time: 0.059 ms"
"Execution Time: 5.775 ms"
```

The ILIKE query took about 85ms too.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT phrase FROM phrase WHERE upper(phrase) ~~* ANY('{*PROTEIN SHAKE,*APPLE PIE}');
"Bitmap Heap Scan on phrase  (cost=148.02..155.34 rows=2 width=18) (actual time=0.264..0.275 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (upper(phrase) ~~* ANY ('{"*PROTEIN SHAKE","*APPLE PIE"}'::text[]))"
"  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=3"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on phrase_phrase_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..148.02 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.247..0.247 rows=4 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (upper(phrase) ~~* ANY ('{"*PROTEIN SHAKE","*APPLE PIE"}'::text[]))"
"Planning Time: 0.281 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.314 ms"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I can't see much benefit in the way that I have indexed.

Please will someone be kind enough to point out where/why I am being a numpty.

I'd like to be able to make a significant difference to this query but I am missing something.

With my best regards, Paul.

Comment: You have an index for the query with `= ANY`, so I am not quite certain what you are after and why. What do you mean by "There might be a few phrases to pull back"?

Comment: I mean that there might be 'n' phrases in the ANY clause. I was initially testing with single values without the ANY, but realised that was unrepresentative. Thanks for reading @Laurenz Albe.

Comment: I feel stupid, but could you explain what an 'n' phrase is?

Comment: "*took about 85ms too*" - no, it did not. The last execution plan shows an execution time of 0.3ms (less than one millisecond). Your slowest query is 20ms, none of them take 85ms.

Comment: Hello @a_horse_with_no_name, the times I have quoted above the explains are how long the query took, the bits in the explain section refer to how long the EXPLAIN took.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe, I simply meant the ANY clause could contain any number of phrases, I probably confused things by stating the obvious  sorry.

Comment: The runtime reported by `explain analyze` is the time to prepare the complete result on the server. Any difference between that and the actual runtime you observe, is caused by the network and the SQL client you are using.

Comment: I don't understand what you are after with the ILIKE queries.  Why are you using ILIKE without a wildcard?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that's interesting. I'll have a think about that as I have no control over the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trigram indexes are a powerful tool, they are slow to update and can become quite large, so if you can do with a B-tree index, use that by all means.

You'd have to test if a trigram index offers performance benefits for longer `IN` lists in your query, but I doubt that it does.

I would stick with the original

```
WHERE upper(phrase) = ANY('{*PROTEIN SHAKE,*APPLE PIE}')
```

and a B-tree index.  Using `ILIKE ANY` instead of `= ANY` does not offer any benefits, no matter which index you use.

At some point PostgreSQL will switch to a sequential scan if the list gets very long, but perhaps it is then correct to assume that the part of the table that has to be scanned is sufficiently big that an index scan would not be faster any more.

Comment: "*will switch to a sequential scan if the list gets very long*" - in  my experience switching from an IN condition to a JOIN against a `values( ... )` clause typically results in much better plans for large IN lists

Comment: OK Laurenze Albe, thank you for taking the trouble to look; I was experimenting and I take your point, thank you.

Comment: @horse_with_no_name, understanding what EXPLAIN is telling me helps, it looks like I have my answer and can give the information back to the engineer concerned. From my existing results, adding a a btree on path makes a big difference when I stick with '=', Execution Time: 0.112 ms as opposed to 5.7ms. Thanks to both you & Laurenz Albe.